# Regex Challenges

Tags: discussion, code-golf, tags

So I had an idea to make a challenge where users have to make a regex expression, based on what I give them. Example:

```
test2 FIND
test3 FIND
test SKIP
```

Then they just answer with the shortest expression they can, but they don't have to use an actual language, just plain regex. Like for this challenge they would do something like:

```
test[0-9]+
```

Then they would explain:

```
test - find the word test
[0-9]+ - find 1+ occurrences of any number
```

Can this kind of challenge become a new tag? Or should I just say it's code golf with only regex allowed?

(Example was really basic, there will be more of a story behind it, and it will be complex so there can be multiple answers where some are shorter)

Comment: See also [meta-regex-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/17718/194). It's possible that questions in this style would be closed as essentially subquestions of that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## This should just be tagged with [regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regex) and [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)

The important question to ask when considering a new tag is

> How will this help people search and find questions they are interested in?

This new tag wouldn't really help anyone. Anyone who was looking for these challenges would search `[code-golf][regex]` and find all of them with no issue so there is no reason to add a new tag.

Comment: So, do regex only code-golfs already exist? Because, all the code-golfs I see are any languages

Comment: @NoahCristino [Yes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/18676/singular-or-plural)

Comment: We actually used to have a tag [tag:regex-golf], inspired by an xkcd comic, but it turns out that it really doesn't convey any information beyond [tag:regular-expression] + [tag:code-golf] so you may as well just use the tags separately, to help people searching for one or the other.